# C# set a default for a type parameter

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, entity

I am trying to extend a class where I optionally want to pass in a type. However, more times than not this will be of type `int` although in some cases this can change so I want to make it dynamic.

However, I want to make it so it defaults to the integer type, and as this extends another class which needs the type, I wasn't sure how to approach it.

I have a BaseEntity setup, in order for me to allow CreatedAt and UpdatedAt columns to be populated when the record is created / updated, this extends the Identifiable class from the JSON API package.

```cs
class BaseEntity : Identifiable {
    ...
}
```

The `Identifiable` class, optionally allows you to pass in the type parameter to the extension if the type of the id is different than the original one specified.

```
class BaseEntity : Identifiable<Guid> {
    ...
}
```

I'm wondering, how can I extend this `BaseEntity` class and  optionally provide a type and pass it in to the Identifiable. Is this achievable or would I need to supply it every time.

```
class BaseEntity<T> : Identifiable<T> {
  // <T> Should default to int if possible.
}
```

```
class AnotherEntity : BaseEntity<Guid> {
  // Allow me to pass in GUID to override the default int type
}
```

```
class AnotherEntityAgain : BaseEntity {
  // Would default to type <int> if nothing specified.
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you can't have a class `BaseEntity` _and_ a(nother) class `BaseEntity<T>` ?

Comment: @Fildor I had a bit of a brain fart, I completely forgot. Thank you for your help!

Comment: We all do, sometimes ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing in C# as an "optional type", that is achieved by having two classes, one with a type and one without. C# allows you to have both at the same time since `ClassName` is considered a different type to `ClassName<T>`

You can achieve the same by creating a type-less class like this:

```
class BaseEntity : Identifiable<int> {
  
}
```

You could also make the class inherit directly from your generic class so you don't need to duplicate code:

```
class BaseEntity : BaseEntity<int> {
  
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response. I know I was missing something! Thank you for pointing that out, amazing. Thank you.